# npx create-react-app -> The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10.x". Got "8.16.0" - Arch Linux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I know this has been here many times, but it just doesn't work. I use Arch Linux. Everytime I try to run

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

or

```
npm create-react-app my-app
```

I get

```
error @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with 
this module. Expected version ">= 10.x". Got "8.16.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

When I type `node -v` I get `14.16.1` and `npm -v` -> `7.10.0`
Looks like the node version doesn't appear update to 14.x version. Maybe?
I have tried updating `sudo npm install -g npm` and `sudo n stable`.

When I try `sudo npm install npm@latest -g` I get a lot of `Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/............`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was that I had installed node via `pacman` and via `Snap Store` (I didn't know about it) and I saw in WebStorm that there is some node v `8.16.0` installed. So i uninstalled the `snap version` and it's working. Looks like `create-react-app` was using the `snap version`

Comment: thanks, man...I really struggled with this error for a long time